# Hadoop: no data-local tasks

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am running a Hadoop job on a 2-node cluster. The replication factor is set to 2, thus, every block should be present on all nodes and all tasks should be data-local. However, the web interface says that the number of data-local tasks is 0.
Any idea where the problem might be?

Comment: Do you see two live datanodes on the web UI? Do you see two active-tasktrackers in the web UI/ running the command `hadoop job -list-active-trackers`? Any messages in the logs of the datanodes? Do you see rack-local tasks on the Web UI?

Comment: @vefthym I found out the answer, i'll post it as an answer. Thank you very much for you help!

Answer (score 1):

I found out where was the problem and I am sorry that I haven't done enough research before asking.

After the completion of the job I looked at the console log and found out that all tasks were actually data - local. Must be some issue with the Web UI showing incorrect information.